# combo box data is not showing in ie

Tags: extjs

```
 xtype:          'combo',
 mode:           'local',
 value:          '1',
 allowBlank:      false,
 triggerAction:  'all',
 forceSelection: true,
 editable:       false,
 fieldLabel:     'Is This Your Territory?',
 name:           'is_territory',
 hiddenName:     'is_territory',
 displayField:   'name',
 valueField:     'id',
 width: 230,
 store:          yesnoStore,
```

this is my code.why this is not showing in ie.

Comment: can you post some more code?

Comment: var yesnoStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        fields: ['id', 'name'],
        data: Ext.decisionlink.yesnos
    });

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code and it runs on IE. Are you defining your `yesnoStore` store? Or maybe it's just the extra coma at the end of your code: `yesnoStore,`, remove it.

Include a store inside your script and the combo works properly:

```
var yesnoStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
    data : [['0','option_1'],['1','option_2'],['2','option_3'],['3','option_4']]
});
```

This example is working on IE, maybe the problem is in your store.

```
{
        xtype: 'combo', 
        mode: 'local',
        value:'1',
        allowBlank: false, 
        triggerAction: 'all', 
        forceSelection: true, 
        editable: false, 
        fieldLabel: 'Is This Your Territory?', 
        name: 'is_territory', 
        hiddenName: 'is_territory', 
        displayField: 'name', 
        valueField: 'id', 
        width: 230, 
        store: yesnoStore
    }
```

Comment: i do this, but the same problem remain.

Comment: can you add some more code about the whole form panel? maybe the problem isn't from this combo. I've tested on IE 9

Answer (score 0):

If you have pasted the full config, the error may come from the extra comma :

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    mode: 'local',
    value: '1',
    allowBlank: false,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    forceSelection: true,
    editable: false,
    fieldLabel: 'Is This Your Territory?',
    name: 'is_territory',
    hiddenName: 'is_territory',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    width: 230,
    store: yesnoStore, // < remove this comma
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work even if the syntax is correct. ExtJS 3.3.1 (confirmed) and below (assumption) have a bug with IE9. IE sets the height of the combo box to 0 upon loading of page.

I attempted the following changes with no success:

- setting height to a fixed size within the config
- creating custom CSS for the class of the combo box list and setting height
- creating custom CSS for the ID of the HTML element that represents the list and setting height

The only solution I found so far:

Upgrade to ExtJS 3.4.0 or above. This will fix this bug and many others tied to IE9.

If you go to the sencha examples and see an example for combo box for 3.3.1 with IE9, it won't work. If you check examples for combo box in 3.4.0 it works with IE9.

Unfortunately for me this is not an option so I'll continue to look for another solution that does not involve upgrade.

Hope this helps.